# python pcolor on an irregular retangular grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can I use pcolor to plot data on irregular grid with rectangular cells? I don't want to plot those cells where the data are absent.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

You can treat it like an image:

```
import numpy as np 
a = 3 # height of each rectangle
b = 14 # width of each rectangle
n = 5 # number of rectangles in each direction
arr = 255*np.ones((n*a,n*b,3),dtype='uint8') #white image array

# generate random colors (RGB format) 
colors = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(n,n,3))

# now fill the image array with rectangles of color
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        arr[a*i:a*(i+1),b*j:b*(j+1)] = colors[i,j]

# and plot the resulting image 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.show()
```

[image]

edit: 
if any cells don't have data, you simply don't fill them with a new color: They're white by default

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. But how to deal with the case that data are absent on some areas

Comment: The concept is the same. Instead of looping over all image cells, you choose the cells with data in them, and fill only those. Before the nested for loops which fill `arr` with color, it is a white background

Comment: I note that setting those cells without data to NAN is more convenient

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(-10,10,21)
y=np.linspace(-10,10,21)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

#synthetic data
x_c=(x[0:-1]+x[1:])*0.5#center of each cell
y_c=(y[0:-1]+y[1:])*0.5
Xc,Yc=np.meshgrid(x_c,y_c)
Z=Xc**2+Yc**2

#values in those cells without data are set as np.nan
Z[9:11,9]=np.nan
Z[0,0:3]=np.nan
Z[3:4,0]=np.nan

#plot the data
fig=plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

Just take the cells without data as nan (not a number).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn7l8.png)